# Conditionally merge items in a sequence

Tags: scala, functional-programming, reduce

I have a list of objects in a sequence `val as = Seq[A]`. `A` looks like this:

```
import java.time.Instant
case class A(t: String, start: Instant, end: Instant)
```

Now I want to merge the element in `as` conditionally: whenever two subsequent, i.e. directly adjacent, items `a1` and `a2` have the same value for `t`, they should be merged into one like this:

```
object A {
  def merge(a1: A, a2: A): A = {
    require(a1.t == a2.t)
    A(a1.t, a1.start, a2.end)
  }
}
```

Note that items that do not directly succeed on another should never be merged, e.g.:

```
Seq(A("a", ...), A("a", ...), A("b", ...), ...) // -> merge the first two elements
```

However:

```
Seq(A("a", ...), A("b", ...), A("a", ...), ...) // -> do not merge any elements
```

There is a [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066465/conditionally-merge-list-elements), but it merges multiple lists, so it is not applicable to my case.

My first approach:

```
as.zip(as.tail)
  .map { 
    case (a1: A, a2: A) if (a1.t == a2.t) => merge(a1, a2)
    case (a1: A, a2: A) => ???
  }
```

There are multiple flaws though. Apart from that I am not sure what to do in the second case (i.e. keep both `a1` and `a2` as-is), this also does not work for more than one subsequent elements that should be merged.

My intuition leads me more towards `foldLeft`:

```
as.foldLeft(???)(A.merge)
```

This solves the issue with more than one subsequent elements that need to be merged. However, it will try to merge all the elements which is not possible with my `merge` implementation.

I could adapt `merge()`, but it remains unclear to me how: if `a1.t == a2.t`, the result type should be a new `A`, whereas otherwise it should 'return' `a1` and `a2` as they were.

My approach to the latter idea was to add these methods to the class `A`:

```
def merge(that: A): (A, Option[A]) =
  if (this.t == that.t)
    (A(t, this.start, that.end), None)
  else
    (this, Some(that))
```

But here, I cannot really use the output of `merge()` in a `foldLeft()` call on the sequence `as`.

The underlying problem is in either approach: how should I handle the fact that sometimes (when `t` matches), I want to add a single new `A` to the new sequence, whereas in the other cases, I need to add two elements.

I am a bit lost on how to tackle this in a functional programming way.
I could of course iterate over the list of `as`, store the ones that should be merged in a new data structure, and generate that again. Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you only want to merge adjacent items?

Comment: @sirius yes, only adjacent items. I've clarified this in the question now.

Comment: Use a fold and compare the current item to the last item of the accumulator. If they match, remove the last item from the accumulator, merge it with the current item and add it back to the accumulator. If they don't match, add the current item to the accumulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on RoberMP's answer, if you use `foldRight` to construct a `List` you can use pattern matching with the cons operator which should be more efficient than tail operations:

```
def merge(sequence: Seq[A]) = {
  sequence.foldRight(List.empty[A]) {
    case (A(t1, x, _), A(t2, _, y) :: list) if t1 == t2 => A(t1, x, y) :: list
    case (other, list) => other :: list
  }
}
```

This works from right to left so that we can use `::` in matching but should still have the intended output.

Answer (score 0):

I think that foldLeft is the proper approach, something like (untested):

```
as.foldLeft(Seq.empty[A])(merge)

def merge(acc: Seq[A], a: A): Seq[A] = {
  if(acc.isEmpty) Seq(a)
  else if(acc.last.t == a.t) acc.init :+ A(a.t, acc.last.start, a.end)
  else acc :+ a
}
```

Notice that there is a lot of tail operations here so don't know if Seq is the better kind of collection for this use case